# Searching codepen.io for anonymous pens

Tags: codepen

I have lost links to two of my pens. I've some vague recollection of their IDs, and have tried switching some of the characters places, changing their case, etc, which, of course was a futile thing to do.

Is it possible to search codepen.io for anonymous pens? I've used the existing search (searched for specific code), but it seems that it only works for finding pens of registered users.

Comment: Have you tried a Google search for the code? That should turn up anonymous pens.

Comment: @freginold I have. Unfortunately, no luck, as of yet. Will keep trying every now and then, in hopes that Google might index it eventually.